# Event bubbling prevention 'ineffective' in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I've been exploring some event handling within the comforts of React's event system, and seeing how that works with the 'outside' world in the DOM.

---

### Example

Here's an annotated sample I've been experimenting with:

```
class FunWithEvents extends Component {
  handleKeyUpWithoutReact(e) {
    console.warn('OMG I handled an event without React ');
    // I noticed that `e.cancelBubble` is `true` here...
  }

  handleKeyUpParent(e) {
    // This handler appears to be under React's supervision...
    console.info('I get prevented :)');
  }

  handleKeyUpTarget(e) {
    console.info("I'm shown in the console :)");
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUpWithoutReact);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyUpWithoutReact);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onKeyUp={(e) => this.handleKeyUpParent(e)}>
        <input onKeyUp={(e) => this.handleKeyUpTarget(e)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As the supported annotations hopefully suggest, I noticed that:

1. The start/target of the event bubbling journey, beginning with the `input`, does indeed trigger the `handleKeyUpTarget` handler as I expected.
2. We prevent further bubbling with `e.stopPropagation` inside `handleKeyUpTarget`.
3. As a result of point 2, the bubble prevention, the `handleKeyUpParent` handler does **not** run, as I expected.
4. However, `handleKeyUpWithoutReact` **does** get called. This caught me off guard, rightly or (probably) wrongly.

---

### My questions

- Why does React not prevent the native event bubbling with `e.stopPropagation()`? Is this by design for interoperability with the shared environment?
- If this is all by design, can I rely on `cancelBubble` being set to `true` as seen in the `handleKeyUpWithoutReact` method?

Thanks in advance!

---

#### Environment

- react 16.3.1
- react-dom 16.3.1
- Chrome 65.0.3325.181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation()`  only stops propagation to events also attached in React. For instance events on `onKeyUp`, `onChange`, `onClick` etc are all Synthetic events in React and in order to stopPropagation for an external event attached using `document.addEventListener`, you need to make use of the nativeEvent and run `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();`

```
class FunWithEvents extends React.Component {
  handleKeyUpWithoutReact(e) {
    console.warn("OMG I handled an event without React ");
    // I noticed that `e.cancelBubble` is `true` here...
  }

  handleKeyUpParent(e) {
    // This handler appears to be under React's supervision...
    console.info("I get prevented :)");
  }

  handleKeyUpTarget(e) {
    console.info("I'm shown in the console :)");
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", this.handleKeyUpWithoutReact);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("keyup", this.handleKeyUpWithoutReact);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onKeyUp={e => this.handleKeyUpParent(e)}>
        <input onKeyUp={e => this.handleKeyUpTarget(e)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**[Working DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/vynwy3lq33)**

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick response & clarity. I had actually tried `e.nativeEvent.stopPropagation()`, which didn't work (...I now get why). I think this mostly comes down to my misunderstanding of the difference between `stopPropagation` & `stopImmediatePropagation`.

Comment: Glad it helped :-)